# L1xL2 array on 8x8 blocks

Tags: c, arrays, block

Given an array of size L1xL2 divide the array by blocks of 4x4. For example the size of the array is 8x8 so there will be four blocks of 4x4.
Here is an example:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8
...............
```

First block 4x4 will be:

```
1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7
```

The second block will be:

```
2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 8 8 8 8
```

I wrote this code (I have a matrix that is stored as an array and it's size is 8*8):

```
for (p = 0; p < nr_blocks; p ++) { 
    for (i = p*4; i < p*4 + 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", array[i*4 + j]);
        }
    }
}
```

But this code take the first block like this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

I want to divide in all the blocks and print them => 4 blocks.

What it is wrong?

Comment: Obviously in order to correctly extract a block you need to know how large the full array is. Your code does not include any references to the array dimensions, only a reference to `array` which is pretty opaque.

Comment: You are indicating a 2 dimensional array:  _an array of size L1xL2_.  However, you do not have a 2 dimensional array described in your example code.  It is a single dimension, i.e. it has only 1 index.  Can you edit your post to show how you have declared this variable?

Answer (score 0):

When your array stores the 8x8 matrix you need access it with the dimension 8.

```
for(p = 0; p < nr_blocks; p ++){ 
    for(i = p*nr_blocks; i < p*nr_blocks + 4; i++) { // please note the change
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf(" %d ", array[i*4 + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is also 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 and not as i want ..1 1 1 1
3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5
7 7 7 7

Comment: My code differs from your code. And I've let it run.

Comment: For an array of 16*16,to divide it in in 8*8 blocks => 4 blocks.for(p = 0; p < nr_blocks; p ++){ 
    for(i = p*nr_blocks; i < p*nr_blocks + 8; i++) { 
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            printf(" %d ", array[i*8 + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
} In this case it doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

***First***
You are describing a 2 dimensional array, but using a 1 dimensional array in your code.

***Second***
Keep in mind C arrays are ***row major order***.  The order you extract elements must obey that construct.

For example, given this 3X4 array:  (3 rows, 4 columns)

```
|1 1 1 1|
|2 2 2 2|
|3 3 3 3|
```

A *C* variable to contain such a matrix could be defined as:

```
int array[3][4]={{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2},{3,3,3,3}};
```

In memory, ***although it is a*** *2 dimensional array* the elements are stored contiguously (Starting from array[0][0]) like this:

```
 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

***The offset from the beginning of the array to any one element*** is given by:

```
offset = row * (number_of_columns) + column;
```

***Working in the opposite way***, if you have an element's linear offset, you can get the row or column as follows:

```
row = offset/(number_of_columns);  
column = offset%(number_of_columns);
```

In the example data you have shown (before you edited your original post),  row 1 contains 4 1s, & 4 2s, then row 2: 4 3s & 4 4s, and so on.  In extracting, you would have to set your for loop indexes to go from 0 to 3 for each of the 4 rows as you traverse the columns to get the first block.   Then use 4 to 7 to traverse the columns again on the same 4 rows to get the second block.

For an 8x8, the same procedure would be used.  Just keep in mind the ***row major order*** of the array.

***Getting the first blocks for 8x8***:

```
int i, j, r=8, c=8;
                  //first row                       2nd   3rd    and so on
int array[8][8]={{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4},{...},{...}, (8 blocks total)...}; 

for(i=0;i<r/2;i++) //traverse 4 of 8 rows
   for(j=0;c/2<j++) //traverse 4 of 8 columns
      printf(" %d ", array[i][j]);  //note this array is a two dimensional array,   
                                    //while you are showing a 1 dimensional array in your example  
                                    //(this is only 1 dimensional:  array[i*4 + j])
```

Change indexes accordingly for remaining blocks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be storing what you call a matrix as one array, that is not a matrix. A matrix is
an array of arrays, thats what is making this difficult for you.

```
for (p = 0; p < nr_blocks; p ++) { 
    for (i = p*4; i < p*4 + 8; i=i+2) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", array[i*4 + j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for (i = p*4; i < p*4 + 4; i=i+4) => only 1 iteration

Comment: ah, yes, sorry about that. Changed the boundaries now, try again please.